# State is behind

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-functional-component, react-pagination

I have a state `pageSize`, user will select the pageSize they wish to size their pages.
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qlJz.png)

I was able to get my currentPage to update, as well as got my list to fit based on pageSize using `useMemo()`.

```
  const PAGE_SIZES = [15, 25, 50, 100];

  function BlogList() {

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(PAGE_SIZES[0]);

  const updatePage = (pageNum) => {
    setCurrentPage(parseInt(pageNum))
  }; 

  const updateRowsPerPage = (rows) => {
    setPageSize(parseInt(rows));
  };

  const currentPaginationData = useMemo(() => {

    const start = Math.floor( (currentPage*pageSize) - pageSize);
    const end = Math.floor(currentPage*pageSize);

    if(currentPage >= Math.floor(blogs.posts.length/pageSize)) {
      return blogs.posts.slice(start, blogs.posts.length)
    }else{
      return blogs.posts.slice(start, end)
    }

  }, [currentPage]);
```

Now, I was having trouble with all my states, they were behind, until obviously the page rerendered, but after some research I used `useMemo()` for `currentPagination`, worked fine, then `updatePage()` is working without an issue. In my experience state is always behind when you try setting morew than one state in a function **LINE 20**. I know its right in front of me, the solution, but I just can't see it, help please!

Comment: One glaring issue I can see is your `useMemo` hook is missing some dependencies in its dependency array

Comment: lol @Nick, Thank you, the simplest fix to a simple problem.